# Proposal to merge Cohen's kappa Q/A

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, merge-questions

In accordance with our policy: [What is our policy on merging duplicate questions?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/what-is-our-policy-on-merging-duplicate-questions), that is, we are supposed to post meta suggestions for merges of questions/answers and take votes on them.

I propose to merge  [Explain Cohen's kappa in a simplest way?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267341) with the [Cohen's kappa in plain English](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82162). It is closed as a duplicate question, but it would make sense to move existing answers as well.

Vote for your choices below.

**Update:** My own answer is moved by me, which brings up other questions, who should move what when and how does *our* policy, which has wasted *our* time contribute to this? However, there is still one more answer left there.

Comment: Please edit the body of your question to be less ambiguous. I never suggested that the merge should be done. I said that I cannot do the merge and that if you wanted a merge you need to go through meta. Particular to your post as I mentioned in the comments of it I think it should be better of as a comment.

Comment: @usεr11852 Why did you bother telling to do something "if you want to" if you did not think it was a good idea. BTW, I do not agree with the comment comment. The rules stipulate to [Provide context for links](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): 

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: I "bothered" telling you to do something even I disagree with it because you have the same rights as any other CV user and it would be wrong to hide (procedural) information from you just because I disagree with what you may do with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this. A thread isn't a duplicate or not based on whether you like the answers on the master thread. If the question is closed as a duplicate, merging seems fine, but you can also delete your answer & repost it there.

Comment: I have now edited the "main" question to have "Cohen's" in the title (and you could have done the same thing), so this part of your argument is not really relevant. I agree with @gung: why don't you re-post your answer in the main thread, if that's where you want it to be?

Comment: @amoeba The last time I did that I ran into a conflict with the moderator who was doing the same thing at the same time. That is, I ported my answer, and he did the same thing simultaneously, which although not a catastrophic outcome, was confusing, and left me wonder how I can port an answer without stepping on someone's toes.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thanks for the information, but (see comment above) this is as clear as frozen mud.

Comment: Regarding your update. I think when it's about your own answer with 0 upvotes (so far), this is a non-issue: simply move the answer yourself and the case is closed. "Merge" is needed when you want to move other people's answers and/or they are upvoted already (so that deleting+reposting would lose upvotes). Note that I am not sure one can move single answers; when a thread is "merged", *everything* gets moved.

Comment: Carl, I edited your question to remove the obsolete parts - please check if you are fine with it (and roll back if you are not).

Comment: @amoeba Yes, I would have liked a total merge to have occurred. Instead, I got mixed signals. Finally, this is beginning to make sense. I moved my answer and in so doing it has gained votes rapidly. My regret is that the OP of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267341/explain-cohens-kappa-in-a-simplest-way  has gained nothing from his contribution.

Comment: @amoeba Yes, I am fine with your edit. However, I do wish there was a less clumsy way of getting a merge done. Our current policy seems a bit open ended, that is, it does not necessarily end in a merge, and, it takes too much effort that I would have been better off using on my answer. Any ideas on this would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, merge both the questions and answer.

Comment: The thread is now closed as a duplicate. I see no reason why they couldn't be merged.

Answer (score 1):

No, do not merge the questions.

Answer (score -1):

We should modify our current policy [What is our policy on merging duplicate questions?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/what-is-our-policy-on-merging-duplicate-questions) so that it does not wind up wasting time, like it did here and have the move done by other means.